# Можно ли сделать такую выборку?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица товары и таблица алиасы. Они ваще никак не связаны. Алиасы как то сопоставляются cms ивыводят информацию о товаре.

Таблица алиасы:
[image]

Таблица товары:
[image]

Тут как видно в алиасах есть столбец в котором строки типа product_id=3000460 это ссылка на товар, так же есть ЧПУ.

Проблема только в том что это таблицы никакими ключами не связаны, так уже б все сделал.

Мне собственно нужно как то сделать выборку из двух таблиц так что бы вывести название товара и его алиас, но я не пойму как это сделать. Может не стандартными способами mysql возможно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если тупо и просто, то

```
JOIN table_alias ON table_alias.url = CONCAT('product_id=', table_product.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не менее тупо и просто

```
FROM товары t
JOIN алиасы a
ON t.product_id = SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.product_id_field,'=',-1)
```